# Rewrite problem, /controller/action instead of /folder/file.php

Tags: zend-framework, url-rewriting, vhosts

I have a script of calling KCFinder.

```
window.open('/kcfinder/browse.php?type=files', ...);
```

it must open a window which contains KCFinder, but when I click the "Browser" button, it generatates error:

> "Uncaught exception
>   'Zend_Controller_Dispatcher_Exception'
>   with message 'Invalid controller
>   specified (kcfinder)' in
>   /home/vhosts/vonline_admin/library/Zend/Controller/Dispatcher/Standard.php
>   on line 248"

I understand this error. It says that controller "kcfinder not found", but kcfinder doesn't require a controller, it's simply a path. Strangely, I run the website successfully in local but when I put it on hosting, it failed.

I think it is related to rewrite problem or routing but I don't know how to fix it.

Vhost: /usr/local/apache2/conf/vhosts/something_admin.conf

> ServerName admin.something.com
>
> ```
>     ServerAdmin foo@boo.com
>     DocumentRoot /home/vhosts/something_admin/www
>
>     SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV development
>
>     TraceEnable off
>
>     <Directory /home/vhosts/something_admin/www>
>             Options -Indexes -Includes -ExecCGI -FollowSymLinks
>             AllowOverride None
>     </Directory>
>
>     RewriteEngine on
>     RewriteRule !\.(js|ico|gif|jpg|png|css|swf|txt|htm|html|xml)$
> ```
>
> /index.php

.htaccess in www:

```
RewriteEngine On  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d  
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]  RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only difference I can see between your htaccess file and mine is in the RewriteRules; I have an asterisk:

```
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: See http://framework.zend.com/wiki/display/ZFDEV/Configuring+Your+URL+Rewriter for more

Comment: Edited. When I use <quote>, it loses "*" character.